# Minecraft will not run with any version

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues, networking, minecraft-launcher

I have been trying to run Pixelmon for Minecraft. I have been able to successfully do this until today. I load up Minecraft like normal and press play, the bar does it's thing and it appears to have loaded. Then it just freezes. I have a dimmed play button and nothing happens. I tried this with normal versions and uninstalled the mods. I also redownloaded the launcher.

I had this same problem on my laptop and my desktop! I don't know why this is because my internet is very good. One thing to note even though it might not be relevant the change log wont load either.

Here is the log:

```
[21:33:44 INFO]: Minecraft Launcher 1.3.5 (through bootstrap 5) started on windows...

[21:33:44 INFO]: Current time is Dec 4, 2013 9:33:44 PM    
[21:33:44 INFO]: System.getProperty('os.name') == 'Windows 7'    
[21:33:44 INFO]: System.getProperty('os.version') == '6.1'    
[21:33:44 INFO]: System.getProperty('os.arch') == 'x86'    
[21:33:44 INFO]: System.getProperty('java.version') == '1.7.0_45'    
[21:33:44 INFO]: System.getProperty('java.vendor') == 'Oracle Corporation'    
[21:33:44 INFO]: System.getProperty('sun.arch.data.model') == '32'    
[21:33:44 INFO]: Refreshing local version list...    
[21:33:44 INFO]: Refreshing remote version list...    
[21:33:44 INFO]: Refresh complete.    
[21:33:44 INFO]: Loaded 2 profile(s); selected 'Brendan4848'    
[21:33:44 INFO]: Refreshing auth...    
[21:33:44 INFO]: Logging in with access token    
[21:33:58 INFO]: Getting syncinfo for selected version    
[21:33:58 INFO]: Queueing library & version downloads    
[21:33:58 INFO]: Download job 'Version & Libraries' started (16 threads, 22 files)    
[21:33:59 INFO]: Download job 'Resources' started (16 threads, 1 files)    
[21:33:59 INFO]: Finished downloading C:\Users\17millb\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\com\google\guava\guava\14.0\guava-14.0.jar for job 'Version & Libraries': Local file matches local checksum, using that    
[21:33:59 INFO]: Finished downloading C:\Users\17millb\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\org\bouncycastle\bcprov-jdk15on\1.47\bcprov-jdk15on-1.47.jar for job 'Version & Libraries': Local file matches local checksum, using that    
[21:33:59 INFO]: Finished downloading C:\Users\17millb\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\net\java\jinput\jinput-platform\2.0.5\jinput-platform-2.0.5-natives-windows.jar for job 'Version & Libraries': Local file matches local checksum, using that    
[21:33:59 INFO]: Finished downloading C:\Users\17millb\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\commons-io\commons-io\2.4\commons-io-2.4.jar for job 'Version & Libraries': Local file matches local checksum, using that    
[21:33:59 INFO]: Finished downloading C:\Users\17millb\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\org\ow2\asm\asm-all\4.1\asm-all-4.1.jar for job 'Version & Libraries': Local file matches local checksum, using that    
[21:33:59 INFO]: Finished downloading C:\Users\17millb\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\lzma\lzma\0.0.1\lzma-0.0.1.jar for job 'Version & Libraries': Local file matches local checksum, using that    
[21:33:59 INFO]: Finished downloading C:\Users\17millb\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\net\minecraft\launchwrapper\1.8\launchwrapper-1.8.jar for job 'Version & Libraries': Local file matches local checksum, using that    
[21:33:59 INFO]: Finished downloading C:\Users\17millb\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\org\lwjgl\lwjgl\lwjgl\2.9.0\lwjgl-2.9.0.jar for job 'Version & Libraries': Local file matches local checksum, using that    
[21:33:59 INFO]: Finished downloading C:\Users\17millb\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\org\lwjgl\lwjgl\lwjgl-platform\2.9.0\lwjgl-platform-2.9.0-natives-windows.jar for job 'Version & Libraries': Local file matches local checksum, using that    
[21:33:59 INFO]: Finished downloading C:\Users\17millb\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\org\lwjgl\lwjgl\lwjgl_util\2.9.0\lwjgl_util-2.9.0.jar for job 'Version & Libraries': Local file matches local checksum, using that    
[21:33:59 INFO]: Finished downloading C:\Users\17millb\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\net\java\jinput\jinput\2.0.5\jinput-2.0.5.jar for job 'Version & Libraries': Local file matches local checksum, using that    
[21:33:59 INFO]: Finished downloading C:\Users\17millb\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\net\sf\jopt-simple\jopt-simple\4.5\jopt-simple-4.5.jar for job 'Version & Libraries': Local file matches local checksum, using that    
[21:33:59 INFO]: Finished downloading C:\Users\17millb\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\net\java\jutils\jutils\1.0.0\jutils-1.0.0.jar for job 'Version & Libraries': Local file matches local checksum, using that    
[21:33:59 INFO]: Finished downloading C:\Users\17millb\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\org\apache\commons\commons-lang3\3.1\commons-lang3-3.1.jar for job 'Version & Libraries': Local file matches local checksum, using that    
[21:33:59 INFO]: Finished downloading C:\Users\17millb\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\com\paulscode\codecwav\20101023\codecwav-20101023.jar for job 'Version & Libraries': Local file matches local checksum, using that   
[21:33:59 INFO]: Finished downloading C:\Users\17millb\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\com\paulscode\codecjorbis\20101023\codecjorbis-20101023.jar for job 'Version & Libraries': Local file matches local checksum, using that    
[21:33:59 INFO]: Finished downloading C:\Users\17millb\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\com\paulscode\librarylwjglopenal\20100824\librarylwjglopenal-20100824.jar for job 'Version & Libraries': Local file matches local checksum, using that    
[21:33:59 INFO]: Finished downloading C:\Users\17millb\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\com\paulscode\soundsystem\20120107\soundsystem-20120107.jar for job 'Version & Libraries': Local file matches local checksum, using that    
[21:33:59 INFO]: Finished downloading C:\Users\17millb\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\com\paulscode\libraryjavasound\20101123\libraryjavasound-20101123.jar for job 'Version & Libraries': Local file matches local checksum, using that    
[21:33:59 WARN]: Couldn't download (link was here) for job 'Resources'

java.lang.RuntimeException: Server responded with 503
    at net.minecraft.launcher.updater.download.assets.AssetDownloadable.download(AssetDownloadable.java:53) ~[launcher.jar:?]
    at net.minecraft.launcher.updater.download.DownloadJob.popAndDownload(DownloadJob.java:107) [launcher.jar:?]
    at net.minecraft.launcher.updater.download.DownloadJob.access$000(DownloadJob.java:12) [launcher.jar:?]
    at net.minecraft.launcher.updater.download.DownloadJob$1.run(DownloadJob.java:89) [launcher.jar:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source) [?:1.7.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.7.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [?:1.7.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.7.0_45]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.7.0_45]
[21:33:59 WARN]: Couldn't download ://resources.download.minecraft.net/a2/a2dbb90f23b0babe7c569ceca28db49d0c112714 for job 'Resources'

java.lang.RuntimeException: Server responded with 503
    at net.minecraft.launcher.updater.download.assets.AssetDownloadable.download(AssetDownloadable.java:53) ~[launcher.jar:?]
    at net.minecraft.launcher.updater.download.DownloadJob.popAndDownload(DownloadJob.java:107) [launcher.jar:?]
    at net.minecraft.launcher.updater.download.DownloadJob.access$000(DownloadJob.java:12) [launcher.jar:?]
    at net.minecraft.launcher.updater.download.DownloadJob$1.run(DownloadJob.java:89) [launcher.jar:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source) [?:1.7.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.7.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [?:1.7.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.7.0_45]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.7.0_45]
[21:33:59 WARN]: Couldn't download (link was here) for job 'Resources'

java.lang.RuntimeException: Server responded with 503
    at net.minecraft.launcher.updater.download.assets.AssetDownloadable.download(AssetDownloadable.java:53) ~[launcher.jar:?]
    at net.minecraft.launcher.updater.download.DownloadJob.popAndDownload(DownloadJob.java:107) [launcher.jar:?]
    at net.minecraft.launcher.updater.download.DownloadJob.access$000(DownloadJob.java:12) [launcher.jar:?]
    at net.minecraft.launcher.updater.download.DownloadJob$1.run(DownloadJob.java:89) [launcher.jar:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source) [?:1.7.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.7.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [?:1.7.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.7.0_45]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.7.0_45]  

[21:33:59 INFO]: Finished downloading C:\Users\17millb\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\argo\argo\2.25_fixed\argo-2.25_fixed.jar for job 'Version & Libraries': Local file matches local checksum, using that    
[21:33:59 INFO]: Finished downloading C:\Users\17millb\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\com\google\code\gson\gson\2.2.2\gson-2.2.2.jar for job 'Version & Libraries': Local file matches local checksum, using that    
[21:33:59 WARN]: Couldn't download ://resources.download.minecraft.net/a2/a2dbb90f23b0babe7c569ceca28db49d0c112714 for job 'Resources'

java.lang.RuntimeException: Server responded with 503
    at net.minecraft.launcher.updater.download.assets.AssetDownloadable.download(AssetDownloadable.java:53) ~[launcher.jar:?]
    at net.minecraft.launcher.updater.download.DownloadJob.popAndDownload(DownloadJob.java:107) [launcher.jar:?]
    at net.minecraft.launcher.updater.download.DownloadJob.access$000(DownloadJob.java:12) [launcher.jar:?]
    at net.minecraft.launcher.updater.download.DownloadJob$1.run(DownloadJob.java:89) [launcher.jar:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source) [?:1.7.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.7.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [?:1.7.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.7.0_45]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.7.0_45]  

[21:33:59 WARN]: Couldn't download ://resources.download.minecraft.net/a2/a2dbb90f23b0babe7c569ceca28db49d0c112714 for job 'Resources'

java.lang.RuntimeException: Server responded with 503
    at net.minecraft.launcher.updater.download.assets.AssetDownloadable.download(AssetDownloadable.java:53) ~[launcher.jar:?]
    at net.minecraft.launcher.updater.download.DownloadJob.popAndDownload(DownloadJob.java:107) [launcher.jar:?]
    at net.minecraft.launcher.updater.download.DownloadJob.access$000(DownloadJob.java:12) [launcher.jar:?]
    at net.minecraft.launcher.updater.download.DownloadJob$1.run(DownloadJob.java:89) [launcher.jar:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source) [?:1.7.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.7.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [?:1.7.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.7.0_45]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.7.0_45]  

[21:33:59 WARN]: Couldn't download ://resources.download.minecraft.net/a2/a2dbb90f23b0babe7c569ceca28db49d0c112714 for job 'Resources'

java.lang.RuntimeException: Server responded with 503
    at net.minecraft.launcher.updater.download.assets.AssetDownloadable.download(AssetDownloadable.java:53) ~[launcher.jar:?]
    at net.minecraft.launcher.updater.download.DownloadJob.popAndDownload(DownloadJob.java:107) [launcher.jar:?]
    at net.minecraft.launcher.updater.download.DownloadJob.access$000(DownloadJob.java:12) [launcher.jar:?]
    at net.minecraft.launcher.updater.download.DownloadJob$1.run(DownloadJob.java:89) [launcher.jar:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source) [?:1.7.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.7.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [?:1.7.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.7.0_45]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.7.0_45]  

[21:33:59 ERROR]: Gave up trying to download ://resources.download.minecraft.net/a2/a2dbb90f23b0babe7c569ceca28db49d0c112714 for job 'Resources'    
[21:33:59 INFO]: Job 'Resources' finished successfully (took 0:00:00.362)    
[21:34:00 INFO]: Finished downloading C:\Users\17millb\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\versions\1.6.4-Forge9.11.1.935\1.6.4-Forge9.11.1.935.jar for job 'Version & Libraries': Couldn't connect to server (responded with 403) but have local file, assuming it's good    
[21:34:00 INFO]: Job 'Version & Libraries' finished successfully (took 0:00:01.412)    
[21:34:00 INFO]: Launching game    
[21:34:00 INFO]: Looking for old natives & assets to clean up...    
[21:34:01 INFO]: Unpacking natives to C:\Users\17millb\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\versions\1.6.4-Forge9.11.1.935\1.6.4-Forge9.11.1.935-natives-2821997222735    
[21:34:01 INFO]: Reconstructing virtual assets folder at C:\Users\17millb\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\assets\virtual\legacy    
[21:34:01 ERROR]: Couldn't unpack natives!

java.io.FileNotFoundException: Source 'C:\Users\17millb\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\assets\objects\a2\a2dbb90f23b0babe7c569ceca28db49d0c112714' does not exist
    at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyFile(FileUtils.java:1074) ~[launcher.jar:?]
    at net.minecraft.launcher.GameLauncher.reconstructAssets(GameLauncher.java:336) ~[launcher.jar:?]
    at net.minecraft.launcher.GameLauncher.launchGame(GameLauncher.java:217) [launcher.jar:?]
    at net.minecraft.launcher.GameLauncher.onDownloadJobFinished(GameLauncher.java:577) [launcher.jar:?]
    at net.minecraft.launcher.updater.download.DownloadJob.popAndDownload(DownloadJob.java:119) [launcher.jar:?]
    at net.minecraft.launcher.updater.download.DownloadJob.access$000(DownloadJob.java:12) [launcher.jar:?]
    at net.minecraft.launcher.updater.download.DownloadJob$1.run(DownloadJob.java:89) [launcher.jar:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source) [?:1.7.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.7.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [?:1.7.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.7.0_45]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.7.0_45]
```

Comment: Try doing a clean install of Minecraft (back up your saves and delete your .minecraft folder). Failing that... I'm not quite certain.

Comment: From the error, you're getting a 503.  That usually means the server borked.  Maybe try it again in a little bit?

Comment: It worked! thanks for the help guys. It must have been the server. but im on a school connection i get back to you when im home

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Error 503 means that the server is not available at the moment. Mojang might be having a bit of trouble with their servers.

The most you can do right now is just try again later.

See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#503) on wikipedia for more info.

Comment: Hmm.. seems a little suspicious that every single resource file downloaded properly except for the one with `…babe…` in the name. Perhaps the "503 Service Unavailable" wasn't actually coming from Mojang's servers, but rather being injected by a school parental control firewall?

Comment: @JamesTheAwesomeDude Honestly I don't think so. Although it is possible, without further details from the OP we will never know. I know from firewalls that I have encountered, I have gotten timeout errors rather than service unavailable

Answer (score 4):

If you've got any sort of parental filter, that's probably what's blocking it.

The file it's trying to download is http://resources.download.minecraft.net/a2/a2dbb90f23b0babe7c569ceca28db49d0c112714
If you look closely at this random number, you'll see that it has a word in it that probably trips a parental filter.

```
http://resources.download.minecraft.net/a2/a2dbb90f23b0babe7c569ceca28db49d0c112714
The offending word is right........................... ^^^^ there.
```

A way around this is to download it with SSL (encryption): https://resources.download.minecraft.net/a2/a2dbb90f23b0babe7c569ceca28db49d0c112714
You'll most likely see this big scary warning about an SSL error that mentions `*.cloudfront.net`. Ignore this error and continue, then copy the file to

- Windows: `%APPDATA%\.minecraft\assets\objects\a2\a2dbb90f23b0babe7c569ceca28db49d0c112714`
- Mac: `~/Library/Application Support/minecraft/assets/objects/a2/a2dbb90f23b0babe7c569ceca28db49d0c112714`
- Linux: `~/.minecraft/assets/objects/a2/a2dbb90f23b0babe7c569ceca28db49d0c112714`

Launch Minecraft again and all will be well!

Answer (score -2):

With the lack of a dev reading or crash report, my best guess would be that minecraft is having troubles getting the natives for 1.6+, as I have seen quite a bit of today. Try running 1.5.2 and see if that works. If not, It's something else.

Try what Unionhawk suggested also. That usually works.